# Ruby on Rails add specific attribute to newly created object in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using a form_for helper to create a new comment on a page. Whenever the submit button is clicked, I also want to give the new comment an attribute, like :this_id => 4. Is this somehow possible in the view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use hidden_field :
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-hidden_field

```
hidden_field(:signup, :pass_confirm)
# => <input type="hidden" id="signup_pass_confirm" name="signup[pass_confirm]" value="#{@signup.pass_confirm}" />

hidden_field(:post, :tag_list)
# => <input type="hidden" id="post_tag_list" name="post[tag_list]" value="#{@post.tag_list}" />

hidden_field(:user, :token)
# => <input type="hidden" id="user_token" name="user[token]" value="#{@user.token}" />
```